# Python - Passing argument of a function in a class

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

is there anybody who could help me to make following code work?

```
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    #
    class DataddoMobileTestFirefox():
        #
        def setUp_and_login(self, browser):
            '''
            Supported browsers are: firefox; chrome
            '''
            global driver
            global email
            global password
            global login_btn
            #
            if browser == firefox:
                driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            elif browser == chrome:
                driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Library/Chromedriver/chromedriver')
            else:
                print('Browser not recognized, exiting...')
                exit()
    #
    #
    # Execute the module
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        DataddoMobileTestFirefox().setUp_and_login(firefox)
```

When I execute the module I get following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "DataddoMobileFirefox.py", line 26, in 
        DataddoMobileTestFirefox().setUp_and_login(firefox)
    NameError: name 'firefox' is not defined
```

I believe I'm close to the target, some hint would help me a lot
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using global in a class? Also why use a class at all if you are only using one method?

Comment: You have to put `firefox` and `chrome` in quotes, in the `if`, `elif` and in the last line.

Comment: The Class contains more methods in my computer, I put here only the one method causing me problems.

Comment: Well don't use global, pass in args and use `self.firefox=firefox` etc.. in your init method, then use self.firefox  in your class and instance.firefox outside

Comment: Is firefox supposed to be an instance variable or the string "firefox"? It isn't being declared as anything in the code you've provided.

Comment: Your class is named `DataddoMobileTestFirefox`. I would expect that it deals with Firefox only. Why are you also attempting to support Chrome within that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firefox` is not defined in your module. I think that you expect it to be a variable.

You could use strings instead:

```
DataddoMobileTestFirefox().setUp_and_login('firefox')
```

Then in your `setUp_and_login()` method:

```
if browser == 'firefox':
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
else browser == 'chrome':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Library/Chromedriver/chromedriver')
```

But probably it is best to set this up in the `__init__()` of your class. And considering that your class is named `DataddoMobileTestFirefox` one would expect that it works with Firefox only, hence there is no need to identify the browser by passing it to `setUp_and_login()`. Just create an instance of the driver in `__init__()`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class DataddoMobileTestFirefox():
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def some_method(self):
        self.driver.do_something()
```

Now you can access the driver from other methods in the class without using `global`.